# What is Tenacious?

Tags: support, badges

I do not understand this badge.

It says: zero accepted answers: for whom ? for me? I found one user having this badge without posting any question. How could be? This is the [user's link](https://askubuntu.com/users/68186/user68186?tab=questions).

Can you clarify it please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original poster is the person who marks answers as accepted.

If you look at the answers that user has posted they have a bunch of accepted answers with a score of zero, thus earning the badge.

I think the idea is to reward people who are quietly answering questions and not getting recognition from people other than the person asking the question.

Comment: one more question: What about the 20% score ?

Comment: If you check my profile you will see that I have 5 zero accepted answers, where is the badge ?

Comment: @kamil the badge reads _Zero score accepted answers: **more than** 5..._ You have 5, not more than 5.

Comment: @kamil ... **more than 5 and 20% of all accepted answers**